# Scan API's with ZAP: Swagger 2:0

Tags: yaml, openapi, swagger-2.0, zap

I am trying to scan my API's using a openapi.yaml file in my pipeline. I am able to load my openapi.yaml file when it tries to scan and hit my endpoint. I am getting the below error.

```
API request successful
Failed to process the OpenAPI file
Response details:
{
  "importFile": [
    "Failed to access URL: http://msst.qa1.csqp.sl.com/api/v2/wbs/v0/answer-product/jobs/qa-weu-des-prod-testing-eu:job:testlarzac9 : org.zaproxy.addon.network.common.ZapSocketTimeoutException : Connect to http://msst.qa1.csqp.sl.com:80 [msst.qa1.csqp.sl.com/35.204.239.105] failed: connect timed out"
  ]
}
```

my api is running in https and here it is trying to connect to http. Tried to add the schemes to point to https also but still same error. So not exactly sure why it is not able to hit the endpoint

```
schemes:
  - http
  - https
```

I am trying to hit the endpoint url and expecting a successful hit but I am getting connect timed out now socket timeout exception.

This is the ps1(powershell) script which I have in pipeline to load the openapi.yaml from the repo.

```
 $load_oas_file = "$zap_url" + "/JSON/openapi/action/importFile/?" + "apikey=$($zap_key)" + "&file=$($OAS)" + "&target="
Write-Output "Calling - $($load_oas_file)"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $load_oas_file
```

This is how I am invoking from the ps1 file. It is able to find the file when it finds the url from the yaml file it is throwing errors for all the api's.

Also I tried to load the same yaml file from local ZAP application. Then there I am getting the below error.

```
    {
 "code": 16,
 "message": "JWT validation failed: Bad JWT format: should have 2 dots",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "auth"
  }
 ]
}
```

This is the same error I get when I hit the api from postman but in postman when I give the correct access token.urls will work in postman perfectly. But I am not sure how to give the token in local ZAP application or when I run in the pipeline.Kindly help if you have more ideas on this.

Comment: How are you importing the file? You can specify the target when you do that, so make sure its right.
If ZAP still cant connect check that the endpoint is accessible from the machine ZAP is running on: https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/why-cant-zap-connect-to-my-website/

Comment: I'm confused first you state "my api is running in https" but then you quote a part of a spec that dictates both should be available. If your spec is wrong, correct it. If it isn't wrong then figure out why http doesn't work from within the container.